# How to get correct onclick ID from PHP loop for Ajax call?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, onclick

How do I get the correct mysql id from a PHP FOR & WHILE loop combo for an Ajax GET command? Right now when I do a test alert, onclick of each href results in the last id being alerted, as opposed to the correct id.

```
   <?php 
    $varRank = 1;
    $pRow = 1;
    $pBlock = 1;
       FOR ($pRow == 1; $pRow < 5; $pRow++){    
            WHILE ($pBlock <= $pRow){

            mysql_select_db($database_cms_test, $cms_test);
            $query = "SELECT * WHERE rank=$varRank";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die();
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $scr = '<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>' .
            '   <script type="text/javascript">' .
            '       function runCounter(){' .
            '       var currentID = ' . $row['id'] . ';' .
            '       var currentRank = ' . $row['rank'] . ';' .  
            '       alert(\'the current id is \' + '. $row['id'] .');' .                
            '       $.get("counter5.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '");' .
            '       }' .
            '   </script>';

            echo $scr;

            $onclkHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="runCounter();" id="' .    $row['song_name'] . '">' .
            '<img src="images/glossy.jpg" width="30" height="30" align="absmiddle" hspace="10" /></a>';
            echo $onclkHTML;    

            $pBlock++;
            $varRank++;
            }
            $pBlock = 1;  // reset
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redefining the same function each time through the loop.

Since you're using jQuery, why not just bind a click handler with it? Give each of these links a class, and use `data-XXX` tags to associate parameters with it:

```
$onclkHTML = '<a href="#" class="counter" id="' . $row['song_name'] . ' data-rank=" . $row['rank'] . " data-id=" . $row['id'] . ">' .
        '<img src="images/glossy.jpg" width="30" height="30" align="absmiddle" hspace="10" /></a>';
echo $onclkHTML;
```

Then just bind a handler to the class:

```
$(function () {
    $(".counter").click(function() {
        var currentId = $(this).data("id");
        var currentRank = $(this).data("rank");
        alert("The current id is " + currentId);
        $.get("counter5.php?id=" + currentId);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if you could give me more information on how to do the binding. If I substitute your $onclkHTML code and then add the script to the head it does not seem to work. I may be missing a step or two.

Comment: For some reason, I re-pasted your code and it seems to be working now :). Thank you so much!